# Calling async method from MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I'm trying to send an SMS asynchronously from an MVC5 controller.

In the controller I call the following method, which is in another class. I don't need any response from the method and don't care if it fails.

```
    public async void SendSMS(string phoneNumber, string message)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                TwilioRestClient twilio = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
                twilio.SendSmsMessage(TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber, message);
            }
        );
    }
```

This isn't working for me, as it seems to be running synchronously. Any tips on how to improve the code and get it into working order are appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you `await` a `Task` (or any other `awaitable`), you're telling the compiler "Im executing this task and yielding control back to you". What happends is that control is returned to the caller until the `Task` finishes execution, and the compiler generates a state machine that will return to the `await` once it completes.

In your method, you dont need any of that.

I will state that im not a fan of fire and forget methods and I think you should add a continuation to handle the Tasks failure even if you dont care if it succeeds. 
If you're using `.NET 4.0` not handling a `Task` exception will cause your process to terminate when the finializer disposes the `Task`.

You can remove the `async` from your method signature since you dont need to `await` and return a `Task` instead:

```
public Task SendSMS(string phoneNumber, string message)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        TwilioRestClient twilio = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
        twilio.SendSmsMessage(TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER, phoneNumber, message);
    });
}
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you.

Comment: Should use `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` rather than `Task.Run`. `Task.Run` is extremely dangerous on ASP.NET; `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` is only somewhat dangerous.

Comment: Care to extend on why it's dangerous? maybe a blog post? :)